# ng-click not firing in ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Ok i have the following:

```
    scope.monthpickerclick = function(scope){
    $window.alert('test'); 
        console.log(scope);
    };
scope.monthpicker = function(alldatesdumparray){

var alldatesdump = booking.getalldates();
var alldatesdumparray = $.map(booking.getalldates(), function(value, index) {
    var dropdates = new Date(value.date);
    var dropdate = dropdates.getDate();
    var month=new Array();
month[0]="January";
month[1]="February";
month[2]="March";
month[3]="April";
month[4]="May";
month[5]="June";
month[6]="July";
month[7]="August";
month[8]="September";
month[9]="October";
month[10]="November";
month[11]="December";
    var dropmonth = month[dropdates.getMonth()];
    var checkmonth = dropdates.getMonth();
    var dropyear = dropdates.getFullYear();
    var joindates = dropmonth + '-' + dropyear;
    var monthyear = checkmonth + '- '
    var today = new Date();
    var mm = today.getMonth(); //January is 0!
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

    if(mm < checkmonth && dropyear < yyyy){

    }else{
        value.date = joindates;
        value.month = checkmonth;
        value.Year =  dropyear;
        return [value];
    }
});
//console.log(alldatesdumparray);
    var dupes = {};
    var singles = [];
$.each(alldatesdumparray, function(i, el) {
    if (!dupes[el.date]) {
        dupes[el.date] = true;
        singles.push(el);
        return singles;
    }
});
return singles;
};
```

HTML:

```
<select >
<option ng-click="monthpickerclick()" class="animate-repeat" ng-repeat="returnpicker in monthpicker(singles)" value="{{returnpicker.date}}">{{returnpicker.date}}</option>
</select>
```

WHich outputs:

```
<select>
    <!-- ngRepeat: returnpicker in monthpicker(singles) -->
    <option ng-click="monthpickerclick()" class="animate-repeat ng-scope ng-binding" ng-repeat="returnpicker in monthpicker(singles)" value="January-2014">January-2014</option>
    <option ng-click="monthpickerclick()" class="animate-repeat ng-scope ng-binding" ng-repeat="returnpicker in monthpicker(singles)" value="February-2014">February-2014</option>
    <option ng-click="monthpickerclick()" class="animate-repeat ng-scope ng-binding" ng-repeat="returnpicker in monthpicker(singles)" value="March-2014">March-2014</option>
    <option ng-click="monthpickerclick()" class="animate-repeat ng-scope ng-binding" ng-repeat="returnpicker in monthpicker(singles)" value="April-2014">April-2014</option>
    <option ng-click="monthpickerclick()" class="animate-repeat ng-scope ng-binding" ng-repeat="returnpicker in monthpicker(singles)" value="May-2014">May-2014</option>
    <option ng-click="monthpickerclick()" class="animate-repeat ng-scope ng-binding" ng-repeat="returnpicker in monthpicker(singles)" value="June-2014">June-2014</option>
    <option ng-click="monthpickerclick()" class="animate-repeat ng-scope ng-binding" ng-repeat="returnpicker in monthpicker(singles)" value="July-2014">July-2014</option>
    <option ng-click="monthpickerclick()" class="animate-repeat ng-scope ng-binding" ng-repeat="returnpicker in monthpicker(singles)" value="August-2014">August-2014</option>
    <option ng-click="monthpickerclick()" class="animate-repeat ng-scope ng-binding" ng-repeat="returnpicker in monthpicker(singles)" value="September-2014">September-2014</option>
    <option ng-click="monthpickerclick()" class="animate-repeat ng-scope ng-binding" ng-repeat="returnpicker in monthpicker(singles)" value="October-2014">October-2014</option>
    <option ng-click="monthpickerclick()" class="animate-repeat ng-scope ng-binding" ng-repeat="returnpicker in monthpicker(singles)" value="November-2014">November-2014</option>
    <option ng-click="monthpickerclick()" class="animate-repeat ng-scope ng-binding" ng-repeat="returnpicker in monthpicker(singles)" value="December-2014">December-2014</option>
</select>
```

which looks fine... 
SO why does monthpickerclick() not fire when i'm selecting an option? 
Chris

Comment: Have you tried `<select ng-change="monthpickerclick()">`?

Comment: it requires ng-model which i dont' have in this case...

Comment: It looks like your function is expecting something to be passed, but on ng-click, it's not passing anything. Also, place the `$` in front of your definition

Comment: my function at least should alert...

Comment: `scope.monthpickerclick()` to `$scope.monthpickerclick()`

Comment: I've used scope across the app it's not that, the ng-click fires when on the select just not in the ng-repeat

Comment: Click event is not supported on `option` tags. `ng-change` is an easy soltuion (along with some dummy temporary model).

Comment: @stewie you got an example?

Comment: the thing it ng-click fires when on the select so thats not an issue but i need scope attached to the option values..I actually need a value that is assigned to returnpicker on the option value...

Comment: All you really need is `ng-model="something"` and `$scope.$watch('something', function(){...})`.

Comment: now that works perfectly!!! if you put it in an answer I'll gladly except!

Comment: `<select ng-model="item" ng-change="monthpickerclick(returnpicker)">
                            <option  class="animate-repeat" ng-repeat="returnpicker in monthpicker(singles)" value="{{returnpicker.date}}">{{returnpicker.date}}</option>
                            </select> `
Is what i currently have but how do i get at returnpickerobject of the selected value??

Comment: Scope.item return the value of the option as in MM/YYYY but not the object...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that you should attach these functions to the select item, rather than the option and use ng-change

```
<select ng-change="monthPickerClick()" >
    <option class="animate-repeat" ng-repeat="returnpicker in monthpicker(singles)" value="{{returnpicker.date}}">{{returnpicker.date}}</option>
</select>
```

Edit: Adding in your suggestion

```
<select ng-change="monthPickerClick()" ng-model="myItem">
    <option class="animate-repeat" ng-repeat="returnpicker in monthpicker(singles)" value="{{returnpicker.date}}">{{returnpicker.date}}</option>
</select>

$scope.$watch('myItem', function(){
    //do something
});
```

Second Edit:

```
<select ng-change="monthPickerClick()" ng-model="myItem" ng-init="savedReturnPicker=[]">
    <option class="animate-repeat" model="savedReturnPicker[returnpicker.date]" ng-repeat="returnpicker in monthpicker(singles)" value="{{returnpicker}}">{{returnpicker.date}}</option>
</select>

//save the returnPicker to a model called savedReturnPicker, then look up with $scope.savedReturnPicker[someDateGoesHere}
```

Comment: how do i return the object returnpicker not just the value... of the option in myitme?

Comment: do you have an exampel function?

Comment: Edited again. Initialize an array, savedReturnPicker=[], then attach to a model by that name and indexed by your .date. Theres more work to be done here but I think you get the idea.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21121923/returning-object-from-ng-repeat-or-ng-options I've just added another question if you want to answer with this

Comment: jsFiddle or some such thing please, easier to help that way.