# returning object from ng-repeat or ng-options?

Tags: angularjs

Ok i have the following:

```
<select ng-model="item" ng-change="monthpickerclick()">
<option  class="animate-repeat" ng-repeat="returnpicker in monthpicker(singles)" value="{{returnpicker.date}}">{{returnpicker.date}}</option>
</select>
```

each option has an object like so:

```
returnpicker: Object
$$hashKey: "02O"
Year: 2014
dailyPrice: "165"
date: "January-2014"
minimumStay: 5
month: 0
monthlyPrice: "4000"
reserved: false
weeklyPrice: "880"
```

how do i get at the object values of each option when selected from my controller? 
currently this:

```
scope.$watch('item', function(){
   console.log(scope.item);
});
```

returns the options string value but i need to get at the month and the year aswell? 
how???

I've also tried:

```
<select ng-model="item" ng-options="o.month as o.month for o in monthpicker(singles)" ng-click="monthpickerclick()">{{item}}</select>
```

but this strips all the other values from the object from the option.

Comment: can you put together a jsFiddle?

Comment: working on it ! the array is a little large currently and the js file is over 2000 lines long..

Comment: see below. you can access all the attributes of returnpicker anywhere inside the options tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<select ng-model="item" ng-options="o as o.date for o in monthpicker(singles)">
```

The `ng-model` links the selected option to `$scope.item` using `o` from `ng-options`.
In `ng-options`, the `as` clause sets the displayed value to `o.date`.

If `monthpicker(singles)` returns an array of obects, `item` will be set the selected object.

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/4ssY6AILQI1Yqrp6GRXg?p=preview)

Comment: You are a star that is exactly what i needed!!! i ahve been fightinh fopr hr's with this!!

Comment: it seemed so simple in principal!

Comment: I keep looking at it again and again and can't figure out how i didn't see this before so simple and so elegant!!

Comment: Yup, just add a regular old option tag inside with whatever you want your default to be. `<option value="">default</option>`. For whatever reason, `value=""` is required. I updated the plunkr. Let me know if this is not what you meant. Good luck.

Comment: Oh, in that case, just set `scope.item`in your controller to the first or whichever you want to be selected by default.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
<select ng-model="item" ng-change="monthpickerclick()">
    <option  class="animate-repeat" ng-repeat="returnpicker in monthpicker(singles)" value="{{returnpicker.date}}">{{returnpicker.date}} {{returnpicker.month}} {{returnpicker.year}}</option>
</select>
```

Edit:
If your option tag looks like this:

```
<option ng-click="monthpickerclick()" > ... </option>
```

Change monthpickerclick() to: monthpickerclick(returnpicker), and feed the object into the function, so its saved to a variable.

```
<option ng-click="monthpickerclick(returnpicker)" > ... </option>

$scope.monthpickerclick(returnpicker){
    $scope.selectedReturnPicker = returnpicker; //save the object
    //other stuff
}
```

Comment: yes but i need the attributes of returnpicker from outside the ng-repeat